# Socket being set up without errors, but no connection

Tags: c++, tcp

I am trying to learn how to use TCP/IP via 2 Linux machines, both of which have functioning internet connections. I tried setting up a server and a client, but I'm not getting a connection, despite not getting any errors during setup.

Server code:

```
int serverSocketFd,clientSocketFd,clientLength,numberOfBytes;
static struct sockaddr_in server_address, clint address;
char buf[256];

serverSocketFd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(serverSocketFd<0){error("socket() call Failed");}

//Clears the allocated space of the sockaddr_in struct before configuration
bzero((char *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address));

server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
//inet_aton should take an IP address in string format and convert it to the proper format for the struct. Returns nonzero for error
if(!inet_aton("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",&(server_address.sin_addr))){error("inet_aton() Failed");}

//Picked a random port number for this test
server_address.sin_port = htons(34567);

//Quick check that I have the expected settings
inet_ntop(AF_INET,&server_address.sin_addr,buf,255);
printf("Listening on %s:%d\n",buf,server_address.sin_port);

if(bind(serverSocketFd,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address,sizeof(server_address)) <0){error("bind() call Failed");}

//At this point, Socket should be prepped to start listening, and waits here until another program makes contact
printf("Waiting on client...\n");
listen(serverSocketFd,5);

//If a client program makes a connection, the 'clinetSocketFd' represents it
clientLength = sizeof(client_address);
clientSocketFd = accept(serverSocektFd, (struct sockaddr *)&clinet_address, (socklen_t *)&clientLength);
if(clientSocketFd < 0){error("accept() call returned invalid");}

printf("CONNECTION ACCEPTED\n");

//Now that a connection is established, wait for a request from client
bzero(buf,256);
numberOfBytes = read(clientSocketFd,buf,255);
if(numberOfBytes<0){error("read() call Failed");}

printf("MESSAGE RECEIVED: %s\n",buf);

numberOfBytes = write(clientSocketFd,"ACKNOWLEDGED",strlen("ACKNOWLEDGED"));
return numberOfBytes;
```

I expect the output to be a message printing my IP address and port, then a wait message, then a message announcing a connection, then a message announcing a request from the client, and the incoming text.

Client code:

```
static struct sockaddr_in server_address;
char buf[256];
int numberOfBytes,e;

clientSocketFd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if(clientSocketFd<0){error("socket() call Failed");}

//Clears allocated space of the sockaddr_in struct before configuration
bzero((char *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address));
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
//The IP address being put in here is the same as the one put in the server code, the IP address of the host machine.
if(!inet_aton("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",&(server_address.sin_addr))){error("inet_aton() Failed");}

server_address.sin_port = htons(34567);

//Same check as server code, look at the target IP and port
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &server_address.sin_addr,buf,255);
printf("Connecting to %s:%d\n",buf,server_address.sin_port);

//As client, we connect the socketFd for the CLIENT to the address struct of the SERVER
e = connect(clientSocketFd,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address,sizeof(server_address));
if(e<0){error("connect() call Failed");printf("Error code %d\n",e);}

//Connection has now been established and can be referenced through clientSocketFd
printf("CONNECTION ESTABLISHED\n");

//Now send a generic message 
numberOfBytes = write(clientSocketFd,"TESTMESSAGE",strlen(message));
if(numberOfBytes<0){error("write() call Failed");}

bzero(buf,256);
numberOfBytes = read(clientSocketFd,buf,255);
if(numberOfBytes<0){error("read() call Failed");}

printf("%s\n",buf);

return 0;
```

I expect the output to be roughly the same, print the target IP and port, acknowledgement messages, and then the received acknowledge.

What I end up seeing, on both machines, is up to the listen/connect stage.

I see the "Listening on/Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:34567", which matches up with the IP address on the machine running the server code. Then it times out. errno is set to ECONNREFUSED.

The connection is never made, but no error comes up before this point, so it doesn't seem like anything went wrong while configuring the sockets.

Can someone explain what is problem is with this code?

Comment: Have you checked the firewall? What does 'iptables -L -n' show? Can you ping from client to server and from server to client? Can you establish a telnet connection to the server port, i.e. telnet <server ip> 34567 ?

Comment: Check also with `netstat` if port 34567 you want to use is not already used by any running process.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Pinging between the machines is failing. But I can actually access the internet, so what does that mean?

Comment: @JeandeyBoris 34567 isnt used, actually all the ports currently in use are only 4 digits. Is it alright to use a 5 digit port number?

Comment: @Zephyr, ping could fail e.g. because a firewall filters all ICMP, or because there is no route between the machines. Try telnet:ing to the port, and do a tcpdump or wireshark on the server.

Comment: @ErikAlapää Ok, doing telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX gives 'Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...' then 'telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out' both ways

Comment: ECONNREFUSED happens at the client, not the server, and it happens immediately, not after a timeout. Unclear what you're asking.